# Is it possible to install a linux desktop environment from a live cd?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, livecd

My question is about Linux in general but lets suppose my ubuntu isn't working property, booting in tty or whatever. I have no internet connection but I have ubuntu live cd. Is it possible to reinstall the desktop environment from live cd?

Comment: Another option is fix your existing install—what errors are you getting? And no reason you can't get network working in text mode...

Comment: @derobert I know but I just wanted to know if I can just use the livecd to fix issues rather than troubleshooting

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is. Either by using the CD as a repository, or by booting into the live session and downloading the package manually and then installing from your normal OS or even by setting up a `chroot` environment. IN the examples below, I am using `apt-get xfce` as the command you will want to run but `dpkg-reconfigure` or whatever else would work as well.

### 1. Use the CD as a repository.

Say that you've screwed up your desktop and are booting to a command line with no internet access (which shouldn't happen, you can have internet even without a GUI). OK, you can put your CD in your drive and then run

```
sudo apt-cdrom
```

If all goes well, that should detect your CD, mount it and parse it for packages. Once that's done, run `sudo apt-get update` to refresh your sources and install your desktop normally. For example: `apt-get install xfce4-desktop`.

NOTE: I have not tested this but it is relatively well documented. See, for example, [here](http://www.debianadmin.com/add-cdroms-to-apts-sources-using-apt-cdrom.html).

### 2. Boot into the live session and get the packages you want.

This one requires that you actually have a working internet connection in the live CD environment. First, boot into your normal (broken) OS and install `apt-offline`. If your system is already broken, you can download the package [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/apt-offline) (make sure you also get the dependencies) and install with

```
sudo dpkg -i apt-offline_1.3.1_all.deb
```

Once you have it installed run

```
sudo apt-offline set xfce-offline.sig --install-packages xfce4
```

Then, take the file that was just generated (`xfce-offline.sig`), boot into the live session and run

```
sudo apt-offline get xfce-offline.sig --no-checksum --bundle xfce-offline.zip
```

Now, boot back into your local system to install it:

```
unzip  xfce-offline.zip
```

That should result in a list of `.deb` files that you can then install manually.

I also found something called [keryx](https://launchpad.net/keryx) which might be worth checking out:

> Keryx is a free, open source application for updating Linux. The Keryx Project started as a way for users with dialup, or low-bandwidth internet to be able to download and update packages on their debian based distribution of linux. Mainly built for Ubuntu, Keryx allows users to select packages to install, check for updates, and download these packages onto a USB portable storage device. The packages are saved onto the device and are then taken back to the Linux box that it originated from and are then installed.

Finally, you can also do all this manually with `apt-get` from the live session:

```
sudo apt-get update --print-uris -y | sed "s/'//g" | cut -d ' ' -f 1,2 | 
  while read url target; do wget $url -O ./$target; done
```

The command above will download all `.deb` files needed to install `xfce`. See my answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104575/22222) for more details on how that works.

#### References

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Installing_packages_without_an_Internet_connection
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1637309&p=10198406#post10198406

### 3. Use the live CD to set up a `chroot` environment.

Setting up the `chroot` is explained in more detail [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109492/22222) but the basic procedure is (replace `/dev/sda1` with whichever partition has your `/`):

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/foo
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/foo
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/foo/dev && 
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/foo/dev/pts && 
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/foo/proc && 
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/foo/sys
sudo chroot /mnt/foo
```

You have now tricked your system into thinking it is booted into your installed OS and you can use `apt-get` normally. Once you've finished, exit the `chroot` with `exit` and reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, any ~700MB CD should install a desktop environment without downloading anything from the repositories.

Keep in mind a livecd is not always the same as the "Install CD", e.g. there is a Debian Live CD and a Debian Install CD.

Comment: How to do it? Suppose I need ro fix xubuntu xfce desktop, would you please give an example from the terminal

Comment: Fix what? How is it broken? Grub? Filesystem errors?