# Debian netinst with usb modem

Tags: debian, system-installation

Im trying to install 64-bit debian on machine with windows and I have no way to connect internet over ethernet at this moment.

I have only ZTE USB modem and Nokia N900 linux mobile phone with wifi hotspot software.

I have downloaded debian-7.6.0-amd64-netinst.iso and I thought that I can "give apt internet" with wifi, with internet shared on my phone, install packages I need. I used netinst because I pay for megabytes and I don't want to pay insane cell phone bill.

However, after netinst setup:

1. My Intel 4965AG network card is not detected (no wlan0 devices, WLAN LED indicator is not glowing)
2. There is no ppp and wvdial, so I can't configure modem and proceed with network installation.

Im afraid, that when I try to download ppp and wvdial manually - I will reboot my laptop forever into windows to download required dependencies.

**What should I do to get my internet working?**

Comment: From what I can see your wireless card uses the iwl4965 driver. See if it is loaded with 'lsmod | grep iwl'

Comment: I'd suggest downloading a bigger piece of Debian than the netinst. You could check the first CD for example, and see if it has what you need. Burning a DVD might also be an option, but possibly overkill. PS. I see you said you pay for megabytes, but in that case, burn the CD/DVD somewhere else? Or buy it?

Comment: Note that there are tools which will help you download all dependencies recursively, so you *could* get the stuff you need and all dependencies in one download. I don't recall how to do this offhand, but I think it has come up on this site. You could ask in the chat.

Comment: @terdon kindly pointed me to http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112358/4671 (see point 2). Maybe that will work for you? Bottom line - use apt-offline.

Answer (score 0):

Try plugging the phone into the usb? This bypasses the built in network adaptor, and also keeps it charged up.

I have a Samsung galaxy-s2 (android). It is connected to my laptop running Gnu+Linux Debian 7 with kernel 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Unfortunately this is never finished maemo-linux phone. No modem over USB. I can only share internet over wifi that eats new battery in 30 minutes.