# Installing gcc offline on a Debian based distro

Tags: software-installation, gcc

I installed Kubuntu 14.10 and it doesn't come with gcc compiler. Since I currently don't have Internet access on my laptop, I got the offline version (a `tar.gz` file) from a friend but I don't know how to install it. Can anyone guide through the installation?

Comment: Have you checked in the installation media (USB, CD,etc.)? Is a .deb or a tar.gz?

Comment: I haven'. Can't be installed from there?

Comment: Yes, you can use `apt-cdrom` for that. See point 1 of my answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112358/22222).